# IDE that can use remote server (which can only be connected to by VPN) to save and compile C/C++ code

Tags: c++, chromebook, ide

Here is the predicament that I am in now.  For one of my classes, we need to make sure our code works on the school's Red Hat server.  I had problems with dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 on my laptop, so I got a chromebook to use as my Linux machine.  Now my question is this: is there an IDE (for C/C++) for Ubuntu that will make it easy to do remote developing?  My chromebook does not have a lot of space, so any solution that is minimalistic would be appreciated.  I also need a way to make a VPN because only computers with a campus internet connection can access the Red Hat servers.

Comment: Why use an IDE? Consider using Vim/Emacs+Make over SSH. Or if you can, find out which version of GCC is used by the server, and install it locally.

Comment: I like having some of the tools that an IDE provides, and I was hoping to use the server to compile to save space

Comment: Depending on the tool, you could get Vim or Emacs to provide some of the same functionality.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Depends. Which tools?

Comment: Project hierarchy, file tabs, and some sort of inline completion/error checking, at a minimum something that places } after you type {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got to work for me.  I installed XFCE with croot, and the IDE that ran best on my Chromebook was CodeLite.  Google has a really nifty extension called Secure Shell which lets you validate your device and use a remote desktop without a VPN.  There is also a SFTP extension that integrates with the native file explorer, though it is a bit buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will work. Mount the thing via sshfs (using standard Nautilus with sftp://user@server/path), add SSH invocations to build commands in the Eclipse project settings, set up remote debugging in Debug/Run settings so it also launches via SSH.